# Как я могу обновить значение параметра у всех элементов RecyclerView при воздействии только на один из них?

Tags: java, recyclerview, android-sdk

Мне необходимо, чтобы при активации режима выбора у всех `CardView` в моём `RecyclerView` отображались чекбоксы.

Текущая реализация влияет на отображение чекбокса только у того `CardView`, который непосредственно попал под действие `SelectionTracker`.

Данные для заполнения хранятся в Room и подгружаются через DAO, при запросе от ViewModel, поэтому я не вижу смысла пихать флаг в модель.

**Journal.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "journal_table")
public class Journal {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;

    public Journal(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj.getClass() == this.getClass()) {
            Journal j2 = ((Journal) obj);

            boolean c1 = (this.id == j2.id);

            boolean c2 = (this.title.contentEquals(j2.title));

            return c1 && c2;
        } else {
            return obj.equals(this);
        }
    }
 }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JournalAdapter adapter;

    SelectionTracker<Long> selectedJournalsTracker;

    ActionMode actionMode;

    private ActionMode.Callback callback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_selection, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            selectedJournalsTracker.clearSelection();
            actionMode = null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new JournalAdapter();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setReverseLayout(true);
        llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        selectedJournalsTracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<>(
                "selectedJournalsTrackerId",
                recyclerView,
                new StableIdKeyProvider(recyclerView),
                new JournalDetailsLookup(recyclerView),
                StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()
        )
                .withSelectionPredicate(SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything())
                .build();

        adapter.setTracker(selectedJournalsTracker);

        selectedJournalsTracker.addObserver(new SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectionChanged() {
                if (actionMode == null) {
                    actionMode = startActionMode(callback);
                } else {
                    if (!selectedJournalsTracker.hasSelection()) {
                        actionMode.finish();
                    }
                    else {
                        actionMode.setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.selected_count_title, selectedJournalsTracker.getSelection().size()));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**JournalAdapter.java**

```
public class JournalAdapter extends ListAdapter<Journal, JournalAdapter.JournalViewHolder> {
    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Journal> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Journal>() {
    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Journal oldItem, @NonNull Journal newItem) {
        return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Journal oldItem, @NonNull Journal newItem) {
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }
    };

    private SelectionTracker<Long> tracker;

    public JournalAdapter() {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    public JournalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cardview_journal, parent, false);
        return new JournalViewHolder(itemView, clickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull JournalViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Journal currentJournal = getItem(position);
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(currentJournal.getTitle());
        if (tracker != null) {
            if (!tracker.getSelection().isEmpty()) {
                holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(tracker.isSelected(getItemId(position)));
            } else if (tracker.getSelection().isEmpty()) {
                holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setTracker(SelectionTracker<Long> tracker) {
        this.tracker = tracker;
    }

    class JournalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textViewTitle;
        private CheckBox checkBox;


        JournalViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        }
    }
}
```

**JournalDetailsLookup.java**

```
public final class JournalDetailsLookup extends ItemDetailsLookup<Long> {

    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public JournalDetailsLookup(RecyclerView mRecyclerView) {
        this.mRecyclerView = mRecyclerView;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ItemDetails<Long> getItemDetails(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {
        View view = mRecyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view);
            if (holder instanceof JournalAdapter.JournalViewHolder)
            {
                final JournalAdapter.JournalViewHolder journalHolder = (JournalAdapter.JournalViewHolder) holder;

                return new ItemDetails<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public int getPosition() {
                        return journalHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public Long getSelectionKey() {
                        return journalHolder.getItemId();
                    }
                };
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_layout">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        tools:listitem="@layout/cardview_journal"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**cardview_journal.xml**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:longClickable="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:contentPadding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**menu_main_selection.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/delete_selected"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
        android:title="@string/menu_journal_delete_title"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="AlwaysShowAction" />

    <item android:id="@+id/select_all"
        android:title="@string/select_all"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внезапно я вспомнил, что класс `JournalViewHolder` у меня объявлен внутри `JournalAdapter`, что даёт мне доступ к инстансу `SelectionTracker`. Соответственно, я просто добавил в конструктор `JournalViewHolder` подписку на событие `onSelectionChanged()`.

```
class JournalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textViewTitle;
    private CheckBox checkBox;


    JournalViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        tracker.addObserver(new SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectionChanged() {
                if (tracker.hasSelection()) {
                    checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (!tracker.hasSelection()) {
                    checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте модель типа:

```
class UiModel(
    val item : YourRecyclerItem,
    val checkBoxState : Int // тут может быть что угодно и не только одно поле. Важно чтоб оно отражало состояние вашего View
)
```

При нажатии на один из элементов генерируйте где-то (например в презентере или ViewModel-и) список элементов с состояниями каждого чекбокса.

После чего просто передавайте этот список в ваш RecyclerView. Если хотите обновлять только те элементы которые изменились, а не все - реализуйте колбек DiffUtils